# How to convert an array from one schema to another in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a JSON array that looks like this:

```js
[{
   "day":"all",
   "client_first":"3",
   "client_second":"2",
   "client_third":"3"
},
{
   "day":"monday",
   "client_first":"2",
   "client_second":"2",
   "client_third":"2"
}]
```

I would like to transform the above into the following

```js
[{
    label: 'all',
    data: [3,2,3]
},
{
    label: 'monday',
    data: [2,2,2]
}]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag. It is not appropriate here.

Comment: You should not name properties like "client_first", "client_second", ...etc, suggesting some order. If you need order, you should have that order explicit using an array from the start. If someone would create the object with "client_second" only and would then add "client_first", you'd get a different order of properties. This is bad, as plain objects should not have such behaviour that depends on the order in which the keys were defined.

Comment: Sorry my misstake trincot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given input:

```js
const input = [{
   "day":"all",
   "client_first":"3",
   "client_second":"2",
   "client_third":"3"
},
{
   "day":"monday",
   "client_first":"2",
   "client_second":"2",
   "client_third":"2"
}];
```

Looks like the semantics of what you want to do align very well with [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

For each values in the input array, map it to an object such that `label` is set by `day` (key rename), and put in to `data` the values of the other entries.
To get the entries (key,value pairs) we use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). We [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get those with `key !== 'day'`. We want an array of the values, so we map the filtered entries (key,value pairs) to only the values. The input is string, but looks like you want it as numbers, so we convert using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#description) function

```js
const output = input.map(obj => ({
    label: obj.day,
    data: Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) => key !== 'day').map(([, val]) => Number(val)),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line of code:
`arr.map(({day,...clients})=>({label:day,data:[Object.values(clients).map(Number)]}))`:

- looping over array and getting the *day* using [`Destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) from object and *clients* using [`rest_parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```js
let arr = [{
   "day":"all",
   "client_first":"3",
   "client_second":"2",
   "client_third":"3"
},
{
   "day":"monday",
   "client_first":"2",
   "client_second":"2",
   "client_third":"2"
}];
console.log(arr.map(({day,...clients})=>({label:day,data:[Object.values(clients).map(Number)]})))
```